# How do I know/get the last or first key in a map?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have a mixin, where I loop over a map. Some of my utilities don't apply for the first or last key in the map.

From time to time, is possible that I add new keys to the map. I can use an `@if="sm-2"` to check directly the value of the key, but I don't want to modify also all 'for/each loops`.

How do I know/get the last or first key in a map ?

```
@mixin utility_generator {
   @each $bp in map-keys($map) {
   /////////////////////////////////
   // @if not last_key/first_key { 
         @include utility($bp) {
            @content
         }
   ////////////////////////////
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reading a very interesting article about how to extract a index number in a sass loop: https://shayhowe.com/finding-index-position-sass-map-loop/. So, using that tecnique, I prefigured your problem to find out a solution for you. But, well, you have to modify your loop and, I know, you said "*no no no no no no no...*". Ok, but maybe 'he doesn't know this solution and it could be useful for him', I thought...

So, take this only as a possible way: for the proper solution we have to wait The Sass Master ;)

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/36ae50657779d40d5537e46f2ad03438

```
$myList: (
"key-1": "value-a", 
"key-2": "value-b", 
"key-3": "value-c", 
"key-4": "value-d", 
"key-5": "value-e", 
"key-6": "value-f"
);

@mixin utility_generator {
   @each $key, $value in $myList {

    $var : index(($myList), ($key $value)) !global;
    $myKey : $key !global; 
    $myValue : $value !global; 

    @if $var !=1 and $var != length($myList){
      @content
    }
   }
}
```